# Webpacker can't find application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm creating a new rails application according to "Getting Started with Rails". The application starts normally in step 4.1. But when i create my first controller, i have a webpack error.

I'm new in webpack, i have red all documentation, but i don't understand what is wrong or missing...

- Windows 10 1903
- ruby 2.6
- rails 6.0.0
- nodeJS 12.11.0

---

```
rails webpacker:install
   identical  config/webpacker.yml
Copying webpack core config
       exist  config/webpack
   identical  config/webpack/development.js
   identical  config/webpack/environment.js
   identical  config/webpack/production.js
   identical  config/webpack/test.js
Copying postcss.config.js to app root directory
   identical  postcss.config.js
Copying babel.config.js to app root directory
   identical  babel.config.js
Copying .browserslistrc to app root directory
   identical  .browserslistrc
The JavaScript app source directory already exists
       apply  C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/install/binstubs.rb
  Copying binstubs
       exist    bin
   identical    bin/webpack
   identical    bin/webpack-dev-server
      append  .gitignore
Installing all JavaScript dependencies [4.0.7]
         run  yarn add @rails/webpacker from "."
yarn add v1.17.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.8.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ @rails/webpacker@4.0.7
info All dependencies
└─ @rails/webpacker@4.0.7
Done in 4.48s.
Installing dev server for live reloading
         run  yarn add --dev webpack-dev-server from "."
yarn add v1.17.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.8.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ webpack-dev-server@3.8.2
info All dependencies
└─ webpack-dev-server@3.8.2
Done in 4.92s.
Webpacker successfully installed �
```

---

```
Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Welcome#index

Showing C:/Users/[...]/site_test/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #9 raised:

Webpacker can't find application in C:/Users/[...]/site_test/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}

Extracted source (around line #9):

7
8      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
9      <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
10 </head>
11 <body>
12
```

Comment: downgrading the version of the node by using nvm helped, I downgraded from 20 to 16 now manifest is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. Unfortunately nothing works.

`rails assets:clobber` return **"error Couldn't find an integrity file"** immediately after deleting node_modules folder. (Works after yarn install --check-files).

and `rails assets:precompile`  return

```
"C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/webpack_runner.rb:23:in `exec': No such file or directory - C:\Users\[...]\site_test\node_modules\.bin/webpack (Errno::ENOENT)"
```

but I found what was wrong: the location in my computer!
probably a name problem ...

Comment: Hi, this happened to me yesterday. I followed the instruction on https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install

Answer (score 52):

run the command

```sh
rails webpacker:install
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: The error went away for me after I updated Gemfile to rails 6.1.4.1 and run the above command.

Comment: This doesn't create any manifest.json file for me.

Answer (score 43):

This error seems  to be the key.

```
Your manifest contains:
{
}
```

Try simply running the `yarn` command in your project directory. That should result in a `manifest.json` file being created - among other things.

If that doesn't work, I found [this issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/997) on github from which I am **verbatim** reciting the following commands that may help you. This will reset all built assets and node_modules.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rails assets:clobber
yarn
rails assets:precompile
```

Check out that link for more information.

Comment: `bundle exec rails webpacker:clobber` removes the public/packs folder from the project, which contains the `public/packs/manifest.json` file, `yarn` brings it back. For anyone with the same problem, better use `clean-webpack-plugin`.

Comment: After trying 430,123 different solutions this finally worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Like Salman's answer above, the command

```
$ rails webpacker:install
```

or

```
$ bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

solves the issue. Which is quite strange for me, as rails does not install webpacker automatically but includes the `javascript_pack_tag` in the default layout anyway. HOWEVER, if yarn complains about your node version, make sure to install the correct one and switch to it, then run the above command again. This simple thing took me an hour to figure out. For instance:

```
$ nvm install 13.7
$ nvm use 13.7
$ rails webpacker:install
```

Comment: You save my life. Thanks! I think the yarn install command also is required, I don't remember

Comment: Great answer - this worked for me! One minor difference is I went onto the Node.js home page to see what the latest version was, and installed it from there. Then I ran `rails webpacker:install`, and then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 12):

I was experiencing this error for more time than I care to mention, until I ran the following steps:

First, webpacker was locked into version 4.0 in my `Gemfile` by default. I upgraded it to 5.0 and ran `bundle update`.

Then:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rails assets:clobber
yarn
rails assets:precompile
```

A new error appeared when precompiling assets:

```
yarn install v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.36s.
I, [2021-04-09T11:04:33.781374 #16062]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/manifest-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js
I, [2021-04-09T11:04:33.781915 #16062]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/manifest-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js.gz
Compiling...
Compilation failed:
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
```

So I edited `config/webpack/environment.js` file to read:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const customConfig = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      dgram: false,
      fs: false,
      net: false,
      tls: false,
      child_process: false
    }
  }
};

environment.config.delete('node.dgram')
environment.config.delete('node.fs')
environment.config.delete('node.net')
environment.config.delete('node.tls')
environment.config.delete('node.child_process')

environment.config.merge(customConfig);

module.exports = environment
```

Only then could the `javascript_load_tag` be loaded. It may not work for everyone, but hopefully saves others time in the same circumstance.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution for future Rails 6.1+ and Ruby 2.7.1+ users.

For me it happened because my webpacker gem was set to a 4.0 version in the `Gemfile`. Once I raised it to a 5.0 version and ran `bundle update`, this error went away for me. It looks like webpacker may have been silently failing when it ran and never created the `public/packs` folder. Changing my `Gemfile` to the newest version of Webpacker solved this error for me.

**Gemfile Changes**

```
DELETED gem 'webpacker',    '~> 4.0.7'
ADDED   gem 'webpacker',    '~> 5.0'
```

Comment: This worked for me as Jun 2021. Rails 6.0.3

Answer (score 6):

Running `yarn add @rails/webpacker` and afterwards `rails webpacker:install` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error message on a Rails 5.2 app where I added Webpacker per the instructions in its README.

After trying some other things, I tried starting webpacker-dev-server (even though it shouldn't be necessary) just to see if that would show a more helpful error. And it did:

```
$ ./bin/webpack-dev-server
warning package.json: No license field
Another program is running on port 3035. Set a new port in  for dev_server
```

I then switched to another project I had running, which also uses Webpacker, and turned off its webpack-dev-server (just ctrl+c:ed the running server). Now when I reload a page in this new project, I no longer get the error. Even without me running webpack-dev-server manually.

You can change this port in `config/webpacker.yml`, in the `dev_server:` section. Don't forget to also update it in `config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb` if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's late but I battled with this for a while and after countless hours spent on research the only solution was to comment line 9 i.e the JavaScript tag which works and allows your code compile but you won't be able to run methods in your application (which utilizes javascript) bringing you back to square one. To solve this problem go to

> "C:/Users/[...]/site_test/public"

and look for a packs folder. If the folder is not present then that is the problem.

Whenever your application runs it compiles and looks for all available files associated to the application.html.erb file and as such you have a stylesheet link tag (application.css) and a javascript link tag (application.js) the error is as a result of a missing application.js.

SOLUTION:
TO SOLVE THIS create a packs folder in ("C:/Users/[...]/site_test/public/")
your public folder and inside the packs folder create a manifest.json file. I.E

> your-app-name/public/packs/manifest.json

After you've done all that, add the code below in your manifest.json file.

```
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-e421b4aa3f716bebdab1.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-e421b4aa3f716bebdab1.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-e421b4aa3f716bebdab1.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-e421b4aa3f716bebdab1.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully that should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

I got this same error - fix for me: I had a `NODE_ENV` environment variable set in my `.zshrc` file that was causing the Webpack build to use the wrong environment config, unsetting that environment variable fixed it for me (`unset NODE_ENV`)

Comment: I do not have that variable in my `.zshrc` and I'm still getting this problem.

Comment: The variable might be getting set elsewhere - trying running `unset NODE_ENV` to ensure it isn't set - clarified answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and running:
`rails webpacker:compile` fixed it

source: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2825#issuecomment-764888322

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by running `bundle exec rails webpacker:install`  this will generate a `manifest.json` file

Answer (score 0):

What solved this issue for me was downgrading nodejs to its stable version (I had accidentaly downloaded the latest instead), then create the new rails app again.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently running Rails in the standard docker ruby container.  Turns out I needed to add:

```
RUN apt-get update & apt-get install nodejs npm -y & npm install --global yarn
```

to my docker file in order to get anything past the initial rails smoketest screen to render.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing here would fix it for me. So I deleted the app and tried again, it worked after that. It seems like there is an install order. If you don't get it correct, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Update Node - >=12

my version - 16.13.1

Use webpacker from git -

```
gem 'webpacker', git: 'https://github.com/rails/webpacker.git'
```

move application.js from app/javascript/packs to app/javascript/

Stop the server, start
This is weird. But this is working for me

Comment: Update: Something to do with resolve paths in webpacker.

Answer (score 0):

It also happens when you have no `yarn` in your environment and try to use `npm` instead. Although packages can be installed by `npm` but webpacker requires `yarn` to run compiling tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your gitignore. You'll need to remove (or comment out) /public/packs

The manifest.json is located in /public/packs and if this folder and it's content are not included on production, webpacker won't be able to correctly route js and css files

Answer (score 0):

Mine was fixed this way after trying lots of different things. My environment was

ruby 2.7.6
rails 6.1.7
node 18.14

I fixed mine by downgrading node to version 16 and running

./bin/webpack-dev-server # stackoverflow article below for more info

[Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Prior to the fix running webpack-dev-server manually showed the following errors

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Answer (score 0):

mine was fixed when i created a manifest.json in public/packs
for some reason this file was not being created

ruby 3.2.2
rails 6.1.7.6

```js
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-9afcbb5693aa87623e69.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-9afcbb5693aa87623e69.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-9afcbb5693aa87623e69.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-9afcbb5693aa87623e69.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made these changes in babel.config.js and it worked for me

@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods

to

@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods

AND

@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object'

to

@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object'

Answer (score -1):

Fropd off somewhere. Empty Manifest. Error: Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Welcome#index I jammed this in public/packs/manifest.json Now she speaks French.

```
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-9afcbb5693aa87623e69.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-9afcbb5693aa87623e69.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-9afcbb5693aa87623e69.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-9afcbb5693aa87623e69.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```