# When running "rails server" why does my localhost refuse to connect on both Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, localhost, port, puma

I'm trying to see my Ruby on Rails app on my localhost, when I run `rails server` it looks like it is running good with no errors but when I open up my localhost at `http://localhost:3000/` it redirects me to `https://localhost:8080/` and says refuses to connect. I am able to open my localhost files with no problems but when I run `rails server` and open localhost with the port it redirects me to `https` instead of `http` no matter what I do. I even tried running with different ports. I am on Ubuntu and my app is using Puma.

**I have done the following so far:**

- Cleared all my cache & history
- Opened incognito window
- Ran `rails server` with different ports
- Changed some `about:config` settings to `false` in firefox
- Have searched `localhost` in 'chrome://net-internals/#hstsand' but says not found
- I've tried the other solutions on this link: [Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https)

**None have worked at all. What could the problem be?**

[I get this error on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8mDD.png)

[And this error on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBi7C.png)

Any advice on this helps! Thanks.

EDIT: Let me know if this needs to be changed, this is how I have my
[etc/host/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIbro.png) set up

Comment: Do you have something like nginx running? do you have any other app running that may act like a server? you can try to bind the server to a specific ip and port with something like `rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 4000` and you can try to connect to `http://0.0.0.0:4000` for example. Another question, when you do the request, do you see anything on the rails server logs? to discard a puma issue, if the request is not getting there then it's something in the OS settings

Comment: I tried `rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 4000` but I still get redirected to `https://localhost:8080/` I don't see any problems in the logs. I'm thinking this might be a problem either in my /etc/hosts settings(not sure how to have them set) or somewhere else because I keep getting redirected to `HTTPS` when I put `HTTP` with a port, which is odd cause I can view all my local host directories, but running with the port doesn't work

Comment: When I use `curl http://localhost:3000/` or `curl http://0.0.0.0:4000` while running rails server it shows `<html><body>You are being <a href="https://localhost:8080">redirected</a>.</body></html>` Not sure if that helps but I'm wondering why it redirects me

Comment: Make you you don't have your app configured as `config.force_ssl = true` for development. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: Do you see anything on the terminal that's running the rails app when you do a request?  to know if the request is reaching rails or if something else is going on. Do you have other apps running? (maybe some docker container, or nginx, or apache)

Comment: Actually I found my issue. I ran `yarn` and then ran `rails s` and my localhost showed up after that! Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

After scrolling through posts and much research my issue was that I did not run `yarn` before running `rails server`. I found this post and referred to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58369306/14365156

But I did not follow those steps exactly, I only ran `yarn` then ran `rails server` and now am finally able to view `http://localhost:3000/`. Hopefully this helps others!