# How to get webpacker to generate public/packs/manifest.json in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, webpacker

I am migrating a rails app to react.  I followed webpacker instructions, but webpacker is not creating /public/packs/manifest.json file.  If I create a new app, I works correctly.  I have tried everything.  Nothing is working.  I am new to rails, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Here are the step that I perfromed:

1. Place in Gemfile
   a. gem 'webpacker', '~> 3.5'; tried it without the second string and other version
   b. gem 'react-rails'
2. bundle install
3. bundle exec rails webpacker:install
4. bundle exec rails webpacker:install:react
5. yarn add react-dom react-on-rails
6. rails generate react:install

Sys config
yarn - 1.22.10
webpack - 5.38.1
webpacker - 4.3.0
react-rails - 2.6.1
rails - 5.2.6
ruby - 2.6.6

THIS IS THE ERROR MESSAGE:

Webpacker can't find hello_react in /Users/lyte/Taichi_Project/taichi_school_v1/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:

1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
   Your manifest contains:
   {
   }

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue but I solved it here. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/69511508/13486752](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69511508/13486752)